# Extracting individual sentences from a text file ... I haven't got it right YET

Tags: c++

As part of a larger program, I'm extracting individual sentences from a text file and placing them as strings into a vector of strings. I first decided to use the procedure I've commented out. But then, after a test, I realized that it's doing 2 things wrong:

(1) It's not separating sentences when they are separated by a new line. 
(2) It's not separating sentences when they end in a quotation mark. (Ex. The sentences ***The string Obama said, "Yes, we can." Then he audience gave a thunderous applause.*** would not be separated.)

I need to fix those problems. However, I'm afraid this going to end up as spaghetti code, if it isn't already. Am I going about this wrong? I don't want to keep going back and fixing things. Maybe there's some easier way?

```
// Extract sentences from Plain Text file 
std::vector<std::string> get_file_sntncs(std::fstream& file) { 
    // The sentences will be stored in a vector of strings, strvec:
    std::vector<std::string> strvec; 
    // Print out error if the file could not be found: 
    if(file.fail()) {
        std::cout << "Could not find the file. :( " << std::endl;
    // Otherwise, proceed to add the sentences to strvec. 
    } else { 
        char curchar;
        std::string cursentence;
    /* While we haven't reached the end of the file, add the current character to the 
       string representing the current sentence. If that current character is a period, 
       then we know we've reached the end of a sentence if the next character is a space or 
       if there is no next character; we then must add the current sentence to strvec. */
        while (file >> std::noskipws >> curchar) { 
           cursentence.push_back(curchar);
            if (curchar == '.') {
                if (file >> std::noskipws >> curchar) { 
                    if (curchar == ' ') {
                        strvec.push_back(cursentence);
                        cursentence.clear();
                    } else { 
                        cursentence.push_back(curchar);
                    }
                } else { 
                    strvec.push_back(cursentence);
                    cursentence.clear();
                }

            }

        }

    }
    return strvec; 
}
```

Comment: How about using a regular expression to identify sentence boundaries?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: This sounds like a job for regex. It won't make your code easier to read but it will be a lot shorter.

Comment: @CJDennis It *will* make the code easier to read.

Comment: @jogojapan Most people find regexes hard to read!

Answer (score 2):

Given your request to detect sentence boundaries by punctuation, whitespace, and certain combinations of them, using a regular expression seems to be a good solution. You can use regular expression to describe possible sequences of characters that indicate sentence boundaries, e.g.

```
[.!?]\s+
```

which means: "one of dot, exclamation mark question mark, followed by one or more whitespaces".

One particularly convenient way of using regular expressions in C++ is to use the regex implementation included in the Boost library. Here is an example of how it work in your case:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>

int main()
{
  /* Input. */
  std::string input = "Here is a short sentence. Here is another one. And we say \"this is the final one.\", which is another example.";

  /* Define sentence boundaries. */
  boost::regex re("(?: [\\.\\!\\?]\\s+" // case 1: punctuation followed by whitespace
                  "|   \\.\\\",?\\s+"   // case 2: start of quotation
                  "|   \\s+\\\")",      // case 3: end of quotation
           boost::regex::perl | boost::regex::mod_x);

  /* Iterate through sentences. */
  boost::sregex_token_iterator it(begin(input),end(input),re,-1);
  boost::sregex_token_iterator endit;

  /* Copy them onto a vector. */
  std::vector<std::string> vec;
  std::copy(it,endit,std::back_inserter(vec));

  /* Output the vector, so we can check. */
  std::copy(begin(vec),end(vec),
            std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout,"\n"));

  return 0;
}
```

Notice I used the `boost::regex::perl` and `boost:regex:mod_x` options to construct the regex matcher. This allowed by to use extra whitespace inside the regex to make it more readable.

Also note that certain characters, such as `.` (dot), `!` (exclamation mark) and others need to be escaped (i.e. you need to put `\\` in front of them), because they would meta characters with special meanings otherwise.

When compiling/linking the code above, you need to link it with the boost-regex library. Using GCC the command looks something  like:

```
g++ -W -Wall -std=c++11 -o test test.cpp -lboost_regex
```

(assuming your program in stored in a file called `test.cpp`).